# Check for particular character sequence NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How can I check if the following format exists in an NSString: two spaces followed by a number followed by a period. Examples are:

```
"  1."
"  2."
"  5."

...

"  100."
```

Does this require a regex? I've started with `[myString rangeOfString:@" [0-9]+\."].location]` but I don't know how to check for any given number 0-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code:

```
NSString *s = @"qw  5.vds";

NSRange range = [s rangeOfString:@"  [0-9]\\." options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL found = range.location != NSNotFound;

NSLog(@"found: %@", found?@"Yes":@"No");

NSUInteger dotLocation = NSNotFound;
if (found) {
    dotLocation = NSMaxRange(range)-1;
}
NSLog(@"dot location: %lu", dotLocation);
```

NSLog output:

> found: Yes
>   dot location: 5

Comment: will location give me the index of the period?

Comment: For the location of the "." use: `NSMaxRange(range)-1`

Answer (score 0):

Regexes would indeed be the easiest way to do this. The expression would look like:

```
'  [0-9]+\.'
```

The [0-9] indicates any digit in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: I get the following warning: "unknown escape sequence '\'." when I do the above.

Comment: Try using a double slash to escape the dot: '\\.'

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would seem to be the way to go. I recommend reading up on [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's an example of how it would work:

```
NSError *regexError;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"  [0-9]\." options:kNilOptions error:&regexError];
if (regexError) {
    // There was some sort of error when creating the regex.
}

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:yourTestString options:kNilOptions range:(NSRange){0, [yourTestString length]}];
if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
    // There was a match
}
```